# how to remove particular li from ul using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML string:

```
var ul = document.getElementById("list");
$("#list").append(
  "<li class='margbottom'>" +
    "<label id='id_'><img src='images/icon-approved1.png' class='imgspace' align='absmiddle'/><span id='categoriesName'>" + categoryName + "</span>: <span id='categoriesValue'>" + value + "</span></label>" +
    "<div class='menuicon'>" +
      "<ul>" +
        "<li><a href='#url' onclick='removeCategory();'><img src='images/icon_minus.png'></a></li>" +
        "<li><a href='#url'><img src='images/icon-searchby-s.png'></a></li>" +
      "</ul>" +
    "</div>" +
  "</li>"
);
```

JS:

```
function removeCategory(){
    alert("Inside removeCategory");
    var elem = document.getElementById('list');
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

I have created dynamically li list and I need to remove it dynamically. bt by calling removeCategory it is removing all element instead of particular one.
Anyone can help?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Select the specific element you want to remove...? I'm not sure what answer you're expecting without showing us your HTML.

Comment: What does the markup look like?  It looks like you're removing the entire element called `list`, which sounds like an entire list...

Comment: (Do not forget to mark an answer as accepted if it works for you)

Answer (score 2):

In this specific situation, you should pass `this` to the removeCategory function and use it as the element.
So, basically -

```
<a href='#url' onclick='removeCategory();'
```

Should be -

```
<a href='#url' onclick='removeCategory(this);'
```

And the function should be -

```
function removeCategory(elem){
    alert("Inside removeCategory");
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

However, adding HTML within the JavaScript like this is discouraged. If you must, at least do not use inline event listeners, but add them using jQuery instead (`$("#list a").on("click", removeCategory);` and then just use `this` within the updated function instead of `elem`).

Also, your code was indeed removing the entire list, because you are always removing the parent element of the element that has the `list` ID.

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery you can do like this:

Add class `'removeLink'` to your  tag. No need for `onClick()` action.

jQuery code to remove:

```
$('removeLink').click(function(){
    var iconDiv = $(this).closest('.menuicon');
    var li = iconDiv.closest('<li>');
    li.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul").find("[particular li selector]").remove();
```

The above is just a starting point. It all depends on how easy access you have to the particular li in question. You can either access it directly (by id) or via the parent in some way.

If possible do this

```
$("#particularLI").remove();
```

Comment: I did it that way because he may not have the id, and it may need a more generic selector

Comment: Okay, but consider `children()` instead of `find()` then (there may be nested lists).

Comment: Suggest you clarify this in your answer, along with the fact that you could select the "particular li" directly and call remove() on it.